# Get wall-clock time of a windows process with command line

Tags: windows, powershell, process, time, wmic

Is it possible to get an uptime from a windows process which is not based on the clock settings of the system?

A linux-based solution is something like:

```
ps -eo comm,etime
```

With some researches, I tried few things on Windows but I didn't find what I was expecting.
For example, using:

```
New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process explorer).StartTime
```

in PowerShell, I got this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNF7y.png]

My problem is that the time is based on a creation date, so if the clock settings is changed for any reason, the result will change so:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIR9W.png]

(I like the negative uptime by the way)

I also took a look at wmic and the problem is the same:

```
WMIC PROCESS GET NAME, CREATIONDATE
```

Is there a field or an option to get a wall-time information like etime?

Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1.  [Wall Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335920/what-specifically-are-wall-clock-time-user-cpu-time-and-system-cpu-time-in-uni) for those unfamiliar with the term (like me).

Comment: Wall-clock time (or wall time) means the human perception of time. I used this expression because I don't want CPU time information or based on Windows current time. Process uptime is the more accurate meaning of my need.

Comment: [This MS technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.heyscriptingguy.aspx) article discusses using .NET stopwatch in powershell, if that helps at all.

Comment: Cygwin's `ps` ignores changes to the current time. However the STIME field only displays the start time in the format hh:mm:ss so you cannot tell how many days it has been running :/

Comment: Interesting ! Cygwin could do the work since I am tracking (and retrieving usage datas) an application with a daemon, this daemon could handle problem with days.
I also like the stopwatch article, could be a bit more tricky but I may like being able to find the time of the previous command ! 

Since it's not as short as a single command line, I have few other things to work on before but I'll give a try on both solutions to give a feedback here as soon as I can !

Comment: Subtract `WMIC PROCESS GET NAME, CREATIONDATE` result from `wmic OS get LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Query a web API? Create some hardware to pump the time over via messages?

Comment: @JosefZ New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process explorer).StartTime is already doing this. I don't want to be dependant from the OS DateTime because if you change it, the uptime is also modified (the creationdate of a process seems to be never changing when the clock system settings is changed)

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I could of course, I'm already not trusting the localDateTime for other purposes. But I found disturbing the fact of not being able to get a reliable process uptime easily and why Microsoft made it dependent on the clock settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to get an uptime from a windows process which is not based on the clock settings of the system?

Cygwin's `ps` ignores changes to the current time.

Drawback:

- The STIME field displays the start time in the format hh:mm:ss so you cannot tell how many days it has been running.

Example output (before changing date):

```
DavidPostill@Hal ~
$ date
Fri, Jul 17, 2015  9:59:11 AM

DavidPostill@Hal ~
$ ps -e -W -p 2612
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     2612       0       0       2612  ?          0 16:51:33 C:\Windows\explorer.exe
```

Example output (after changing date):

```
DavidPostill@Hal ~
$ date
Fri, Jul 17, 2015 11:59:29 AM

DavidPostill@Hal ~
$ ps -e -W -p 2612
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     2612       0       0       2612  ?          0 16:51:33 C:\Windows\explorer.exe
```

The value of `STIME` is unchanged - `16:51:33`

Notes:

- `16:51:33` is the time from yesterday when I restarted by machine.
- The `STIME` field displays the start time in the format `hh:mm:ss` so you cannot tell how many days it has been running.

---

#### Cygwin ps is missing option -o to format the output

Cygwin uses a custom ps program that can also handle windows processes
but which does not support all those options.

However, `procps` supports `-o`.

Drawbacks:

- The STIME field displays the start time in the format hh:mm:ss so you cannot tell how many days it has been running.
- It does not handle Windows processes.

Comment: It's been a while... I accepted this answer because I think Cygwin should be ok for most people. My use case didn't comply with it but it was very specific !